# How do I access a particular Enum value in another class?

Tags: java, enums

Basically, I'm trying to create my own Craps game with a "betting" feature where you can play and see an update of how much money you've won or lost. To do this, I've created the Craps Class which allows the player to play Craps a single time, and my code is reliant on a custom enumeration that I call "Status" (private static enum Status) with the values of `PASS_WON`, `PASS_LOST`, `DP_WON`, `DP_LOST`, `KEEP_ROLLING`.

The part I'm struggling with is the first step of the `BetMoney` class. I want to start by saying if at the end of the Craps Game, if the status is WON, then money is added to the money you have already if the status is LOST, money is subtracted, etc, etc. However, I cannot access the private Status enum that I declared in the Craps Class, in the BetMoney class in order to do this if statement. I am completely unsure how to create a getter for an enum like this. Is there any way to "get" the values of the enum in my BetMoney class, so I can use them in an if Statement? What I want to do is something like `(if newGame [craps object].getGameStatus() == PASS_WON)`, increment wins.

I do have a getter for a private variable "GameStatus" which is used to loop through the game. This serves as the current GameStatus and it's of the type Status from the enumeration that I have. I just can't use it in BetMoney properly.

Summary:

Right now, I have 2 classes. Craps class (which is used to play an individual game of Craps) and then a BetMoney (which will contain win/loss tracker) and money tracker.

Status is currently a private static enum in my Craps class, and I'm trying to use it in BetMoney.

```
//This is where my Status Enum is declared, these are all in Craps Class
private static enum Status {
        PASS_WON, PASS_LOST, KEEP_ROLLING, DP_WON, DP_LOST;
}; 

//Status variable for each single game
private static Status GameStatus;

//Getter for the single game status (there's also a setter)
public Status getGameStatus() {
    return GameStatus;
}

//Throughout Craps, I have a lot of code similar to this, where 
//getPoint gets the original "point" (first sum rolled) and for certain 

//sums, you win or lose the game, and GameStatus is set for use later.
switch (CrapsGame.getPoint()) {
        case 7:
        case 11:
            CrapsGame.setGameStatus(Status.PASS_WON); 
}

//How I keep looping:
while(CrapsGame.getGameStatus().equals(Status.KEEP_ROLLING)) { 
   ...logic to keep the game working...

}

//At the end, I return GameStatus.
```

Comment: You'll need to change the access to something other than `private`, and either qualify the constant with the class name, or import it.

Comment: Could you share the code you have so far?

Comment: Hi Andy. I was under the impression that making it public was bad practice. I want to make sure that I'm following good practice to build better habits in the future whenever my code gets more complex. Is it okay to make the enum public?

Comment: Keep the variable private and add a public getter method for it.

Comment: @MCEmperor I've edited my question adding a few snippets of the code that I have.

Comment: @Jason That's what I've tried but whenever I go to use getGameStatus in the BetMoney Class, and try to see if it equals a certain value in the enumeration, it wouldn't let me do it.

Comment: @AndrewHe - It's generally good practice to use *encapsulation*, part of which is making object fields private. However, your *enum* class itself is private. You won't be able to access its constants outside the containing class, unless you change it to something other than private.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've declared the enum class private. This prevents its use outside your Craps class.

```
private static enum Status {
    PASS_WON, PASS_LOST, KEEP_ROLLING, DP_WON, DP_LOST;
};
```

You'll need to make this something other than private. It is good practice to make each class as inaccessible as possible. But you know that you want to access it outside Craps. So, if Craps and BetMoney are in the same package, you could simply remove `private` to make the enum package-protected:

```
static enum Status {
    PASS_WON, PASS_LOST, KEEP_ROLLING, DP_WON, DP_LOST;
};
```

Inside BetMoney, you'll either need to import the constants you want to use, or qualify their use with their enum class name, as you've done in your example code (e.g., `Status.PASS_WON`).

Comment: It would actually need to be qualified by `Craps.Status.PASS_WON`, since the enum is a nested class within `Craps`.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you. So there's no way to do this while still keeping Status a private enum?

Comment: @DevinH - Unless you import the enum Status itself, in which case `Status.PASS_WON` will work.

Comment: @AndrewHe - Not if Craps and BetMoney are two separate top-level classes. On a nested class, the `private` qualifer limits access to the body of the top-level type that encloses the class. This information hiding is a good thing if you only need to use the nested class within the enclosing class. It's not a good thing if you need to use it outside the enclosing class.

Comment: Ahhhh so would it be better to put BetMoney and Craps in the same class? Thank you.

Comment: No. In object-oriented programming, it's useful to define classes of objects that you're working with. Each class should have a single responsibility - to represent exactly one kind of thing your application is working with. It is good to minimize accessibility to the minimum required. But throwing everything into one class, so that you can use `private`, would defeat the purpose -- everything could access everything. It's better to design the class model and its public API first, then work on representation and access control.